# replace string url in certain path

Tags: ruby

I have link to image

```
link = "https://ecs7.sandal.net/img/cache/500-square/product-10/2019/6/16/719184/719184_de07958e-9e6b-491a-ae61-2291220be643_1080_1080.jpg"
```

the path after /img/cache which is 500-square is the size of the image.

the link is dynamic. but the size is alway after the cache/ path.

and the rest of link after the size path is product folder, so it can be ignored.

500-square is to small for image i want. so i have to change to 900 or some other size.

so the link will be like this below

```
https://ecs7.sandal.net/img/cache/900/product-10/2019/6/16/719184/719184_de07958e-9e6b-491a-ae61-2291220be643_1080_1080.jpg
```

how to replace 500-square to 900 using ruby string ?

thanks

Comment: Do you just want to replace the number or do you want to ensure it is after img/cache/ as well?

Comment: yes, only the number, 500-square to 900, just slash between cache/ and /product. the rest is not needed to be changed. i try to split but if i join back i lose the /. thank you @SaraTibbetts

Comment: You can use `arr.join("/")` to add the slashes back in

Comment: omg it works, thanks @SaraTibbetts. i did not think about that. u should answer it so i can accept it, or not, depends on you. but thanks anyway

Comment: `link['500-square'] = '900'` would work.

Comment: @Stefan I don't think string slice assignment (e.g. [String#\[\]=](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D)) is used very often, but it's certainly handy. It's an in-place method, but non-intuitively returns the replacement string on the RHS of the assignment. That's correct behavior, but I found it surprising. Thanks for pointing out this alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string on the "/"

```
link_list = link.split("/")
```

Then you can replace "500-square"

```
link_list[link_list.index("500-square")] = "900"
```

Then join it together with the "/"

```
link = link_list.join("/")
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you create a temporary array, instead of simply working with strings directly? This code will fail if `"500-square"` isn't present in the string. It might be a feature, though.

Comment: I did this purely based on what the OP had stated they had done in the comments and what wasn't working from what they had tried

Comment: It makes sense from a pedagogical point of view, then. You might just want to add that it's possible to achieve the same result directly with strings.

Answer (score 2):

### Replace Whole Substring

There are many ways to do this, depending on how much your data varies and how well-structured it is. However, if you know that your *link* variable will always want to replace the substring `500-square` then you can simply use String#sub to replace the value. For example:

```
# replace entire substring
link.sub '500-square', '900'
#=> "https://ecs7.sandal.net/img/cache/900/product-10/2019/6/16/719184/719184_de07958e-9e6b-491a-ae61-2291220be643_1080_1080.jpg"
```

If you don't want to mess with regular expressions, this is the way to go. Additionally, you can still anchor the expression to a portion of the URI path if there might be other potential matches. For example:

```
# anchor expression with slashes
link.sub '/500-square/', '/900/'
#=> "https://ecs7.sandal.net/img/cache/900/product-10/2019/6/16/719184/719184_de07958e-9e6b-491a-ae61-2291220be643_1080_1080.jpg"
```

If you need to key off something else, such as location within the URL or other attribute, then you may need a more complex solution. The code above will certainly address the use case posted, though.